# I have successfully loaded a form into a <div> element using jQuery $.Ajax. I need to know how to submit that form using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have used **.on()** of jQuery for event delegation and to set up a 'submit' event handler for the dynamically the loaded form e.g.

```
<script>

    $(document).on('submit','#my_form_id',function(e){


                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();


                    $.ajax({

                           url:$this.href,
                           type:"POST",
                           data: $('#my_form_id').serialize(),
                           dataType: "html"

                     }).done(function(update_result){

                         $('#id_of_div_that_will_hold_the result').html(update_result);  
                     });

                     return false;

      });



  </script>
```

**But it is not working as the form gets submitted directly not asynchronously.**

**Also where should the above script be put in the main page or in the page that contains the HTML code for dynamically loaded form? I ask this as it seems the script is not being called**

Any general short example will help and be highly appreciated. I cannot provide the code here as it is too long in MVC architecture using codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to POST the form:

```
$("#my_form_id").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
      // put any code handling return values here
    });
});
```

The [$.submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) works the same as `$.on('submit')` but easier to read and type. The `$(this).serialize()` function will convert all the form data into a string to be submitted to the server.

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` is what will stop the form from being posted synchronously - it will skip the default function of the submit button, and do your ajax post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the default event handler (submit) from firing.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my_form_id', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax form submision code goes here....
});
```